# It's add to hash_mapp strings with same keys

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap

I thought that into hash_table I can't add same values. I mean insert (key1,value1) and then again insert it.

But in my case it adds same strings with same hashes.
I was trying to keep BYTE* as a key but it still add same strings.

I've used HCRYPTHASH*,HCRYPTHASH and it still works incorrectly.
Maybe it is needed to override methods of hash_map(In C# I had got troubles when key in Dictionary was my own class so I'd just overridden GetHashCode method and redefine Equals method)

```
#include <hash_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinCrypt.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"crypt32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::hash_map<BYTE*,std::string> table1;
    HCRYPTHASH hash1;
    HCRYPTPROV prov1;
    std::string a1="noname";
    std::pair<BYTE*,std::string> pair1;
    //insert first hash
    ::CryptAcquireContext(&prov1,NULL,NULL,PROV_RSA_AES,0);
    ::CryptCreateHash(prov1,CALG_MD4,0,0,&hash1);
    BYTE* arr=(BYTE*)a1.c_str();
    DWORD len0=strlen((char*)arr)+1;
    ::CryptHashData(hash1,arr,len0,0);
    BYTE get[16];
    DWORD len=16;
    ::CryptGetHashParam(hash1,HP_HASHVAL,get,&len,0);
    pair1.first=get;
    pair1.second=a1;
    table1.insert(pair1);
    /*----------------*/
    HCRYPTHASH hash2;
    HCRYPTPROV prov2;
    std::string a2="noname";
    std::pair<BYTE*,std::string> pair2;
    //insert second hash
    ::CryptAcquireContext(&prov2,NULL,NULL,PROV_RSA_AES,0);
    ::CryptCreateHash(prov2,CALG_MD4,0,0,&hash2);
    BYTE* arr1=(BYTE*)a2.c_str();
    DWORD len1=strlen((char*)arr1)+1;
    ::CryptHashData(hash2,arr1,len1,0);
    BYTE get1[16];
    DWORD len11=16;
    ::CryptGetHashParam(hash2,HP_HASHVAL,get1,&len11,0);
    pair2.first=get1;
    pair2.second=a2;
    table1.insert(pair2);
    for each(std::pair<BYTE*,std::string> x in table1)
    {
        std::cout<<x.first<<" - - "<<x.second<<"\n";
    }
    ::system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Check the **return value** of `insert`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that most of your code is entirely irrelevant to your observation: the `std::hash_map<BYTE*, std::string>` (which is actually **not** a standard C++ class despite the somewhat misleading use of `std::`; the hashed map in C++2011 is called `std::unordered_map`) uses the `BTYE*` as the key. The two **pointers** being passed in are clearly different. The hash values you seem to compute are put into the **value** of the mapping, not its key.

Although it is sometimes useful to use a pointer as a key, you typically want to use a values type, e.g. `std::vector<BYTE>`, as a key.

Comment: ` std::hash_map<std::vector<BYTE>,std::string> table1;
 std::pair<std::vector<BYTE>,std::string> pair1;
 std::vector<BYTE> *a=new std::vector<BYTE>();
 std::vector<BYTE>::iterator iter;
 a->insert(a->begin(),5);
 pair1.first=*a;
 pair1.second="noname";
 table1.insert(pair1);`
In such simple code it says that cannot convert vector<_Ty> to size_t

Comment: This just means that there is no default hash function of `std::vector<T>`.